# Exam type questions in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, button, radio-button

I have a page new.jsp. I want to

```
<table>
 **Question 1. What is the total value of 2+6?**
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="abc" value="6">6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="abc" value="7">7</td>
</tr>`
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="abc" value="8">8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="abc" value="9">9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="abc" value="next"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Like this I have to make 100 questions, for this it is n't possible to create 100 jsp pages, so what are those alternatives?? Please guide me. When User will click Next button then he will move to the next question like this up to 100th question he will move and answers selected by him will be saved automatically, how can i do it?? Please help me

Comment: Create a database of questions, possibles answers and a correct answer and create a dynamic page that reads from the database and generates the question page. You don't need to re-create 100 JSP pages and it'll be easier to maintain and support 1 page instead of 100 JSP pages. Make the page dynamic instead of static.

Comment: the role of a JSP is to be dynamic so the server has to retrieve the correct informations, like the label of your question and the possible answers.
Then you could create your own tag for example, but the creation depends on which framework you choose (struts, spring mvc, etc.)

Comment: @BuhakeSindi ya thnx for d info but for one question answer is selected by the user then after clicking next button  , next question will be fetched from database, like this??

Comment: Question is selected, click next, store the user information and his/her answer and fetch the next set of question and answers to be displayed.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi ya thnx but for english, a passage is to be displayed in jsp page, how can i select a passage of 300 words from database?

Comment: A database can store an entire book content, if set right. 300 words is how long in character length?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi thnx a lot sir....me trying nw :)

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a template JSP which is almost same but has variables around like:

```
<td><input type="radio" name="abc" value="${option1}">${option1}</td>
```

And when user clicks next, you say goto a servlet/another jsp, fetches next question from DB/text/excel file and sets the option1, option2 accordingly, so it renders same page with same layout but with different parameters.

Comment: ya thnx but for english, a passage is to be displayed in jsp page, how can i select a passage of 300 words from database?

Comment: you could have varchar column in your DB and you could still use variable of String type.

Answer (score 1):

As Almas stated you'll want to create a template with JSP and use a database. One database table will hold the questions and the other holds the possible answers. For example your database tables could be:

```
CREATE TABLE question (id int auto_increment, question varchar(1000), sort int, primary key(id));
CREATE TABLE answer (id int auto_increment, question_id int, answer varchar(1000) sort int, primary key(id), foreign key (question_id) references question(id));
```

When rendering the page to query the next question you'll need the 'sort' value of the question just displayed. With that value to get the next question run:

```
SELECT id, order, question FROM question WHERE sort > ? ORDER BY sort LIMIT 1;
```

That will get you the next question. Once you have the question, to load the answers run the following with the parameter being the question id

```
SELECT id, order, answer FROM question WHERE question id = ? ORDER BY sort;
```

(Now you could do just one query instead of two but that gets more complicated and I'm trying to keep this simple. If I was you I'd make it one query.)

I hope that helps.

Thanks,
David